# How to solve # 7 in SQLZOO select names section

Tags: sql

All:

I am learnig SQL now, but stuck at   **#7**   of

> http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_names

```
Bahamas has three a - who else?

Find the countries that have three or more a in the name
```

Thanks

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?  Happy to answer it, but just asking.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No, it is from SQLZOO, just self study

Comment: Does it matter if it's an 'a' or an 'A', i.e case sensitive or case insensitive?

Comment: @Kuan Please review the answers given below.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try using the `LIKE` operator:

```
SELECT name FROM world
WHERE name LIKE '%a%a%a%'
```

If you want to do case-insensitive search for either `a` *or* `A` then you can use the `LOWER()` function:

```
SELECT name FROM world
WHERE LOWER(name) LIKE '%a%a%a%'
```

**Edit:**

We could also use `REGEXP` here:

```
SELECT name FROM world
WHERE name REGEXP '(.*[a]){3,}';
```

However, for this particular example, I would go with `LIKE`, because it probably would perform better, and less of an overhead, than using `REGEXP`.

Comment: I think this is correct but their system doesn't recognise this answer as good yet in the list of countries all countries have 3 or more 'a' letters.

Comment: Case insensitive or not?

Comment: @jarlh The link he provided gave this example: `Bahamas has three a - who else?`  I will update my answer to include an option for both upper and lower case.

Comment: Afghanistan has 3 a's, but with different case.

Comment: @jarlh The OP does not go _nearly_ into this depth of concern...so why are you splitting hairs here?  The OP used lowercase `a`, which means either it wants all lowercase `a` or _all_ `a/A` regardless of case.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, sorry if I wasn't clear enough, just gave an example of a country name with three a's, but not returned if looking just for lower case a.

Comment: I updated my answer to give a query which takes `LOWER()` of the `name` column to get around this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try this query:

```
SELECT name
FROM world
WHERE LEN(name) - LEN(REPLACE(name,'a', '')) > 2
```

Comment: @Kuan: Change to this as replace takes 3 arguments.

SELECT name
FROM world
WHERE LEN(name) - LEN(REPLACE(name,'a', '')) > 2

Comment: LEN is product specific, and no dbms is specified in the question. Which dbms does LEN work with?

Comment: @jarlh yours is a trap question

Comment: @DrewPierce Yeah he hit me with a trap too but I got out of it ^ ^

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to solve this lecture with regular expressions but couldn't match this correctly.

```
regexp '(.*[a]){3,}'
```

Should match 3 or more 'a', which it does but:

"Sao Tomé and Príncipe" with 2 a's is matched by `LIKE '%a%a%a%'` which is the correct answer.

Im curious what's going wrong here?

Comment: Your `REGEXP` pattern is correct, [see here](http://rextester.com/VTDJF11924).  Maybe there was some other problem with your query.  In any case, I would go with `LIKE` for this particular question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name
FROM world
WHERE LENGTH(name) - LENGTH(REPLACE(lower(name),'a', '')) >= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is worked for me:**

`SELECT name FROM world WHERE name LIKE '%a%a%a%';`